# Grails sitemap issue with url rewrite

Tags: grails, sitemap

I am using url rewrite in my website to rewrite my url from "www.mydomain.com/user/profile?id=1" to "www.mydomain.com/profile/users_firstName-1"

Now I have a generated a sitemap for my website and added the sitemap.xml file into my user directory with rewritten profile urls of all the users.

But according to the sitemap protocol : 
"The location of a Sitemap file determines the set of URLs that can be included in that Sitemap. A Sitemap file located at http://example.com/catalog/sitemap.xml can include any URLs starting with http://example.com/catalog/ but can not include URLs starting with http://example.com/images/."

so my question is that will my profile url's work or I will have to mention the orginal path to make it working.

I have also tested this xml file in :
http://www.webmasterwebtools.com/sitemap-validation/index.php

and it says the xml file is well formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should give the original path as the original path is also going to hit the same link. And it follows the standards of the sitemap.